# Scraping TripAdvisor Body Review Problem “Read More”

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am new in Python and Scraping.

I am scraping reviews's TripAdvisor and I have found a problem when I scrape the reviews. I can't expand all body. Also, depends on the review it can have "Más" (read more) or not

[image]

I am trying with this code:

Selenium:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[text()="Más"]').click()
```

Thank youu

Comment: What is wrong with that code? What is the issue, exactly, what have you done to try to solve this?

Comment: Hi  AMC, I am sorry  if I don't explain fine. I am scraping TripAdvisor and I have a problem when I extract the reviews. I can extract the reviews but not at all. I need to click in  "Más" (in English Read More). On the other hand, depends on the review, it can "Más" or not. I need to expand all "Más" in the review's page. For example in this link you can see in the review with title  "Experiencia muy agradable" and link "https://www.tripadvisor.es//Restaurant_Review-g187495-d2489299-Reviews-or680-Martin_Quiroga-Valladolid_Province_of_Valladolid_Castile_and_Leon.html" Thank you